# Function to skip characters

Tags: c, strings, parsing

A very simple function that can be used such that it returns a pointer to the first character on which `func` returned `0`. However, it also handles escaped lines.
Needless to say this could be very useful in my cases, for example skipping spaces when converting a csv to an array.

```
/** Skip characters from @src
* @func: isspace, isdigit, isalpha, etc can be used
*/
char *skip (const char *src, int(*func)(int))
{
    char* p = NULL;

    for(p = src; *p != '\0'; p++)
    {
        if(!func(*p))
        {
            if(*p == '\\')
            {
                p++;

                if(*p == '\r') /* Will probably have to deal with annoying MS-style line endings when the source string is loaded from a file */
                {
                    p++;
                }
                if(*p == '\n')
                {
                    continue;
                }
            }

            break;
        }
    }

    return p;
}
```

Example test usage:

```
int ishspace (char ch)  { return(ch == ' ' || ch == '\t'); }

int main (void)
{
    char* p = skip(" \t \\\n \t Hello World\n", ishspace);

    printf("%s", p);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

> > Hello World

> >

Comment: What should happen if func returns true on '\\', like `ispunct`?

Comment: @PavloSlavynskyy then the loop continues (the `\\` is consumed) as it is supposed to be? If the line is escaped though, I imagine it will break on the NL

Comment: That should be easily solved by moving the inner condition toplevel and adding "else". Do you think I should edit it or wait for a complete review. Hopefully there are better, potentially faster ways to achieve this, as it is often used a lot and in performance-sensitive context.

Comment: Many aren't aware of the standard `strcspn` function. It returns the length of a string until the point where one out of several characters has been found. `size_t i = strcspn(str, " \t\r\n"); /* whatever characters you like to stop at */ char* next = &str[i+1];` Seems it would be useful for your specific scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Compilation problems

`NULL` isn't defined - either use the constant `0` or include `<stddef.h>` before `skip()`.  Alternatively, just initialise `p = src` instead of this *dead store*.

Type mismatch assigning `src` to `p` - we should make them point to the same kind of object, either both `const char` or both `char`.  (In C++, we would overload the function with two variants, each accepting and returning the same type; in C we need to give the two functions different names).

In the test program, `printf` is undefined - include `<stdio.h>` to fix this.

We can't pass `ishspace()` to `skip()` as it has type `int(*)(char)` but we need an `int(*)(int)`.  That's easily fixed by making it accept `int` instead.

`ishspace` is a reserved identifier that might conflict with future library versions of `<ctype.h>`.  Choose a name that's allowed for user functions (simply inserting `_` after `is` is sufficient).

## Design issues

The comment advertises that the `is…()` functions from `<ctype.h>` can be used, but that's dangerous with the present implementation because these functions accept only *positive* characters (or `EOF`).  We need to cast to `unsigned char` before widening to `int` when calling these.

When `func()` returns true for `'\\'`, the backslash-newline concatenation doesn't occur.  I think that's the wrong choice, as conceptually, joining continuation lines is usually the first step in parsing.  In either case, we should document this in comments.

When we see a backslash not followed by newline, we return a pointer to the character immediately after the backslash (or after the carriage-return immediately following).  That seems wrong to me; I would expect the return value to point at the backslash itself.

A single test is nowhere near enough for this function.  I'd like to see a variety of input strings and predicates that together test the entire specification of the function.  Some things that are not tested:

- the empty string
- input strings with backslash not followed by newline (including some with the backslash at the end of the string).
- input strings containing consecutive escaped newlines (`"\\\n\\\n"`)
- input strings containing carriage returns
- input strings with escaped and non-escaped CRLF
- predicate function that always returns true
- predicate functions that return true for `'\\'`
- predicate functions that return true for newline or carriage-return

We should make the tests self-checking - return a non-zero value from `main()` if any test returns the wrong result.

---

## Modified code

I renamed `src` to `s` as we don't need the separate `p` variable.

```
/** Skip characters from @src until @func returns false
 * This function skips over escaped newlines before applying @func
* @func: isspace, isdigit, isalpha, etc can be used
* @return: a pointer into @src or to its terminating null character
*/
const char *skip (const char *s, int(*func)(int))
{
    for (;;)
    {
        /* first skip escaped newlines */
        if (*s == '\\')
        {
            if (s[1] == '\n')
            {
                s += 2;
                continue;
            }
            if (s[1] == '\r' && s[2] == '\n')
            {
                s += 3;
                continue;
            }
        }
        /* then test whether we're looking at a skippable character */
        if (!*s || !func((unsigned char)*s))
        {
            return s;
        }
        /* next character */
        ++s;
    }
}

/* skip() for mutable strings */
char *skip_m (char *src, int(*func)(int))
{
    return (char*)skip(src, func);
}
```

I've made only minor changes to the test.  You should really replace this with a full unit-test suite.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int is_hspace(int ch)  { return ch == ' ' || ch == '\t'; }

int main(void)
{
    const char* p = skip("\\ \t \\\n \t Hello World", is_hspace);
    printf("%s\n", p);
}
```

Comment: For me a bit hard to read with the on-line braces, but isn't `if (p[1] == '\r' && p[2] == '\n')` accessing out of bounds memory area?

Comment: Just reformatted the code, saw it's part of the outmost condition and as such it doesn't access out of bounds area. Anyway, for-loops without a condition look so weird

Comment: I've reformatted to use separate lines for substatement-opening braces, and refactored to express this as an infinite loop, with the ++p at the end.  That means that amount we add to p in those conditions is now the actual number of characters to advance (2 and 3, respectively) instead of needing to be one less due to the increment in the control expression.  I think that's clearer.

Comment: We could use `strncmp()` instead of those individual comparisons, but I didn't want to include `<string.h>` just for that - and if this truly is tight code, I expect better performance from this version rather than the much more general library function.

Comment: It is indeed clearer. I also thought of using `strncmp`, but I don't think with 2 characters it pays enough for the overhead of a function call (even though I think the optimization will force `strncmp` to inline the comparison)

Answer (score 4):

#### Code Review

**Problem #1**

In the function header `char *skip (const char *src, int(*func)(int))`, in particular, making the argument `char *src` a `const` does not make much sense, as it is not regarded as so throughout the function.

For instance, `p` is assigned `src` in the for loop, despite the fact that `p` is not a pointer to a const char. `p` is also returned from the function, despite the fact that the function does not return a const char (it is just char).

Hence, you should either

1. Drop the `const` from `const char *src` or
2. Make the function return a `const char` and make `p` a `const char`
   as well (if you are doing this, you must also make `char* p` a
   `const char* p` in the main function)

**Problem #2**

Also in the function header `char *skip (const char *src, int(*func)(int))`, in particular, making the argument `int(*func)(int)` does not make sense. At least, according to your "test usage".

For instance, you have defined your `ishspace` function as `int ishspace (char ch)`. I do not know if this was intentional or not, but this translates to `int (*)(char)` (because it accepts char as an argument), not `int (*)(int)` as your `skip` function requires. For your information, `isspace()`, `isdigit()`, `isalpha()`, etc. (the ones that are defined in `<ctype.h>`, I assume) all accept `int` as an argument.

Hence, you should either

1. Change the argument from `int(*func)(int)` to `int(*func)(char)`;
   though, this is probably not what you want
2. Change the `ishspace` function in the usage example to accept `int`
   instead of `char` (this will not affect the overall capability of the
   function anyways)

This can be improved. Using something like a `switch` statement for comparing the values of `*p` would also be more readable/efficient, if you will have to compare against 6 or more escape sequences in the future.

**"Parting thoughts"**

In terms of design choices, I am personally against passing `isspace()`, `isdigit()`, `isalpha()`, etc. as an argument of `int(*func)(int)`. Instead, it may be better to actually just use some those functions within the `skip` function, or try to create separate functions that checks separate things. This is due to a couple of reasons:

1. It gives the users (programmers) too much power by allowing them to
   pass in virtually whatever function they want. This could generate
   all sorts of undefined behavior and even security issues.
2. It can conflict with your internal checks for certain escape
   sequences, like `'\\'` in particular. For instance, `ispunct()`
   function (assuming that we are talking about the functions in
   `<ctype.h>`) will return non-zero for `'\\'`, which is **definitely not**
   what you want.

Comment: Your "readability" improvement changes the logic . OP's only advances `p` on an `\r` following a '\\'.  Yours advances on all `\r`s.

Comment: I don't believe you can give programmers "too much power".  You just need to document what happens with the power you give them.    If application end users were able to pass in arbitrary functions, that would be a different story.

Comment: @AShelly Edited accordingly. I did not see that for the if-statement. As for giving programmers "too much power", I think my **Problem #2** demonstrates exactly what you are talking about where "end users were able to pass in arbitrary functions", despite the said documentation.

Comment: I commented that 2. was basically a missed design consideration. Instead of editing the question, I just left it as-is in case someone already started a C/R. I didn't paid attention for the `ishspace` accepting char too, that's definitely not correct. I only have to agree with @AShelly that instead of purposely restricting programmers, I should just carefully document the function.

Answer (score 3):

On the function arguments:  `src` should definitely be a `const char*`, that is a signal to the caller that this function guarantees not to modify the string.  Enforce that guarantee by making `p` a `const char*` also.

And that guarantee implies that you should then return an `const char*`, so that this function is not a backdoor for the caller to cast away constness.

I would probably rename `func` to `testfunc` or `predicate`.

I don't think there is any problem with accepting an arbitrary test function. Tons of code out there uses callbacks.  This isn't end-user facing code, and you are not responsible for limiting the "power" of programmers who use your code. You should clearly document the conditions under which this function is called, and what is done with it's output, so that programmers understand what's happening.  For example

`// calls 'testfunc' on every non-escaped character in 'str' until it returns zero.`

`testfunc` should take a `char` argument.  Yes, `isalpha` and the like take integers, but the spec says

> [isalpha's] argument is an int, the value of which the application shall ensure is representable as an unsigned char ...

Since you have chars, and you are responsible for ensuring chars are passed to isalpha, I would change the type and write an adapter

```
int alphatest(char c) { return isalpha(c); }
```

I don't understand the goal of the escape skipping part.  Right now you skip  calling the test func on any character following a `'\\'`, but only if testfunc doesn't match the `\\`.  That seems odd.

I would probably simplify the spec to:  "doesn't test any character after an `\`".  Or maybe "never matches on escaped newlines", if that's what you intend.  Either way, I'd refactor to

```
for(p = src; *p != '\0'; p++)
{
    p = skip_escapes(p);
    if (p == '\0' or func(*p) == 0)
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

Where `skip_escapes` returns `p` or the first character after a valid escape sequence starting at `p`, whatever you decide the escape sequence to be.

Comment: `int alphatest(char c) { return isalpha(c); }` is UB when `c < 0` and not `EOF`.  In that case "value of which the application shall ensure is representable as an unsigned char" was not met.

Comment: "Right now you skip calling the test func on any character following a '\\', but only if testfunc doesn't match the \\. That seems odd."
Please, take a look at my comment on the answer above.
Also The function only explicitly skips "\", "\\r" and "\\r\n", not every character following a `'\\'`